# How to install Intel XDK in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: software-installation, intel-graphics

Tried to install [Intel XDK](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-xdk) but the process stops after the `ls xdk_web_linux64`. It extracted but I cannot `ls` as it says it cannot access.

```
No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Intel SDK](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-xdk) software is provided in a `.tgz` compressed file that needs to be extracted before anything else. Although you mentioned *it extracted*, considering your trouble with the commands, I'll start by mentioning a couple of way to do it, just in case.

**The GUI way**

Right-click the file - `xdk_web_linux64_3641.tgz` - and select `Extract here` or double-click and extract to anywhere you like (in your `/home/your_username`). The end result either way should be a folder named `xdk_web_linux64_3641`.

**The command line way**

Open a Terminal with CTRL+ALT+T or search for it in the Dash. Then:

```
cd /home/your_username/Downloads
```

**Note:** The above assumes the downloaded file is in the `Downloads` folder. Replace `Downloads` with the actual name of the folder and `your_username` with your username.

Next, in order to extract it, please do:

```
tar -xvzf xdk_web_linux64_3641.tgz
```

The end result should be the same as the aforementioned `Extract here...`

Now `cd` into the extracted folder and do

```
./install.sh
```

to start the installer. Follow the instructions to complete the installation.